# What's the error in the last line of the code?

Tags: functional-programming, syntax-error, ocaml

I'm writing the function that takes an integer list as an input and separates prime and composite numbers into two lists:

```
#prime_sep [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6];;
- : int list * int list = ([5; 3; 2], [6; 4; 1])
```

Here's my code:

```
let rec is_prime n a = match n with (*at the begining put a=3*)
| 2 -> true
| x when x<=1 -> false
| x when x mod 2=0 -> false
| x when a*a>x -> true
| x when x mod a=0 -> false
| _ -> is_prime n (a+2) and
l1 = [] and l2= [] in
let rec prime_sep l = match l with
| [] -> (l1,l2)
| h::t when is_prime h 3 = true -> h::l1 and prime_sep t
| h::t when is_prime h 3 = false -> h::l2 and prime_sep t;;
```

And I get a syntax error message in the last line:

```
Error: Syntax error
Characters 348-349:
  | h::t when is_prime h 3 = false -> h::l2 and prime_separator t
  ^
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The keyword `and` is not an operator. It's used to build up a series of mutually recursive definitions.

You want the `&&` operator where you have `and`.

**Update**

After you make the change from `and` to `&&`, you still have at least one problem. These are the last lines of your code:

```
let rec prime_sep l = match l with
| [] -> (l1,l2)
| h::t when is_prime h 3 = true -> h::l1 && prime_sep t
| h::t when is_prime h 3 = false -> h::l2 && prime_sep t
```

The `let` expression in OCaml looks like `let v = expr1 in expr2`. You have `expr1` (the match expression or more technically a `fun` containing this expression), but you don't have `expr2`. I.e., you are missing the `in` keyword and the expression that follows.

Because every `let` expression requires an `in`, this is a syntax error. But another way of putting this is that you define a function named `prime_sep` but you don't ever call it anywhere. If you add `in` plus a call, this solves both problems.

I have a feeling there are still more problems, but I hope this helps make progress.

Comment: You mean in last two rows?  Now I have a syntax error pointing to the `;;`, at the end of the last row.

Comment: Of course you need to fix both uses of `and`, which are wrong for the same reason. After that you have `let` with no matching `in`.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if this is too helpful but this is a version that I was able to throw together for the problem.

```
let is_prime n =
  let n = abs n in
  let rec is_not_divisor d =
    d * d > n || (n mod d <> 0 && is_not_divisor (d + 1)) in
  n <> 1 && is_not_divisor 2;;


let prime_sep l = 
  let rec prime_sep_helper lst l1 l2 = 
    match lst with
    | [] -> (List.rev l1, List.rev l2)
    | h :: t -> 
      if is_prime h then
        prime_sep_helper t (h::l1) l2
      else
        prime_sep_helper t l1 (h::l2)
  in
  prime_sep_helper l [] [];
```

Comment: I think you just need to add one more  `;` at the end and it will be fine. Is there a way to nest `is_prime` in `prime_sep`?

Comment: There certainly is a way to nest is_prime like you could write the have is_prime right above prime_sep_helper but I kind of prefer this more split up style because this way other methods in your program could access is_prime if needed.